# Apache2 Proxy cross-origin request cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, apache2, mod-proxy

I have a Proxy set on a folder in my subdomain `/internal` and I am attempting to get the cookies header on my Node.JS App from the request but it is unset when the request is made from a different origin but with the same domain.

Here is the proxy in my virtual host for `api.example.com`:

```
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /internal http://localhost:8760
ProxyPassReverse /internal http://localhost:8760
```

When I make an AJAX request from `api.example.com` to `api.example.com/internal/ajax` the cookie header is present when I console log it on my Node.JS App.

AJAX Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.example.com/internal/ajax",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false
});
```

**The problem is** when I make the exact same AJAX request but from `sample.example.com` to `api.example.com/internal/ajax` it's like the cookie header gets deleted but every other header is still present

Comment: I believe you need to set withCredentials to true if you want to send cookies in a cross domain request - for jquerty ajax, see "ajax" documentation about `xhrFields`

Comment: @Bravo I am trying to get the cookies from the request header, not the set-cookie response header. Thanks though.

Comment: your issue is that $.ajax is not sending cookies in the request - read the documentation and learn about "withCredentials" flag in XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Bravo You were correct, my apologies. Some reason I always thought withCredentials was only if you were trying to set cookies.